# Rails 4 Strong Parameters issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am attempting to create an applicant on my controller I can see the params has in the applicant_params method and can access the hash using pry to validate the hash is correct. When the create method then fires all the @applicant values are nil? I must be missisng something basic here?

```
def applicant_params
  params.require(:applicant).permit(
    :first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :contact_number,

  binding.pry
end
```

end

```
def create
  @applicant = Applicant.new(applicant_params)
  binding.pry
  respond_to do |format|
    if @applicant.save
      format.html { redirect_to @applicant, notice: 'Applicant was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @applicant }
    else
      binding.pry
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @applicant.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it still fail without the `binding.pry`? That call returns nil and will mess things up...

Comment: I am not sure why it is failing. I can see the correct parameters at the breakpoint. Then when it returns to the create method @applicant has nothing but nil values. I created a new project and moved things over and it seems to be working. Wonder if something just failed in the during generate?

Comment: I'm still suspicious ABOUT the breakpoint. `binding.pry` is just another Ruby expression, and its return value (`nil`) will be what's returned by `applicant_params`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it well Matt, at the point within applicant_params, the break point there (binding.pry) shows the correct params hash. So at that point if I params it shows the values. Then it continues back to the create method and applicant variable has all nil values. I checked the spelling of all properties and spent quite a bit of time double checking everything. Once I finally gave up and created a dummy project and ran a scaffold just to see and the syntax was identical to mine. So I recreated the project and things are working fine now. Your guess is as good as mine.